# how to update this kind of table

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
/*
Duties
*/

duty_id , duty_name 

//duty_names are duty1,duty2,duty3,duty4,duty5

/*
Members-Duties
*/

id , members_id , duty_id 

/*
Members-Duty-Scores
*/

id , members_id , duty1 , duty2 , duty3 , duty4 , duty5
```

I want to update table **'Members-Duty-Scores'** but first i want to know the duties a  member is assigned by querying the **'Members-Duties'** table.A member can do all or some duties.How do i update table **'Members-Duty-Scores'**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Members-Duty-Scores SET
duty1 = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Members-Duties WHERE duty_id = 1 AND Members-Duties.members_id = Members-Duty-Scores.members_id) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
duty2 = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Members-Duties WHERE duty_id = 2 AND Members-Duties.members_id = Members-Duty-Scores.members_id) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
duty3 = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Members-Duties WHERE duty_id = 3 AND Members-Duties.members_id = Members-Duty-Scores.members_id) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
duty4 = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Members-Duties WHERE duty_id = 4 AND Members-Duties.members_id = Members-Duty-Scores.members_id) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
duty5 = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Members-Duties WHERE duty_id = 5 AND Members-Duties.members_id = Members-Duty-Scores.members_id) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```